# How to restrict image acess to authorized website users only

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm working on a project for which I need to store user uploaded images in a secure way. Currently, I'm hosting the website on AWS s3 (static content) with cloudfront. The backend is deployed separately behind application load balancer.

The use case is - A user uploads image(s) from his desktop which go to a bucket in s3. I've set the bucket policies so that everybody is able to upload images to it (since it's a public website). Now, I've to restrict the image access only to the user who has uploaded it. i.e If user A uploads images A1, A2, A3, only he should be able to view those and not user B.

Currently, if I get the url through browser inspect tool, I can view the image directly without any restrictions. This defeats the purpose of "securely" storing images on the website. 
Could someone let me know about any standard practices, pointers to this problem?
Would generating the image url each time through backend with some special hash be over engineering?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [AWS Amplify's Storage module](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage) and the [File Access Levels](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage#file-access-levels) docs. Out of the box it supports a `private` level that lets users upload into (and view from) only their own namespaced prefixes in the bucket. This sounds like exactly what you're after.